# Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW) crashes in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

HP 340S G7 laptop has inbuilt wifi device and it does not work, don't know is it driver issue or an hardware issue? This system have only Ubuntu20.04 OS installed in it.
Have also tried installing backport iwlwifi but still this issue persists.

Please find below system details -

`uname -r` output:

`5.4.0-52-generic`

`lshw -C network` output:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:72224000-72227fff
```

`rfkill kist all` doesn't give any output at all.

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` output:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW) [8086:34f0] (rev 30)
    DeviceName: Intel Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW) [8086:0074]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`dmesg | grep iwl` output:

```
[    2.358872] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8794:f51dd362
[    2.399945] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.440272] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.446512] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.446543] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 65.3.35.22
[    2.447480] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.527221] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x338
[    2.715041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: c0:b8:83:62:a4:b7
[    2.882974] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   31.022804] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Enter CT Kill
[   31.220631] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[   31.220774] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   31.220778] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000042, count: 6
[   31.220781] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 59.601f3a66.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-59.ucode
[   31.220785] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000092 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   31.220788] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[   31.220790] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   31.220793] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CB39E | branchlink2
[   31.220795] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004B539A | interruptlink1
[   31.220797] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004B539A | interruptlink2
[   31.220799] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C5AB4 | data1
[   31.220802] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data2
[   31.220804] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[   31.220806] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   31.220808] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   31.220811] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000B844 | tsf hi
[   31.220813] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   31.220815] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01A3A4DA | time gp2
[   31.220818] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[   31.220820] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003B | uCode version major
[   31.220823] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x601F3A66 | uCode version minor
[   31.220825] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000332 | hw version
[   31.220828] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C89008 | board version
[   31.220830] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8054FD00 | hcmd
[   31.220832] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
[   31.220835] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | isr1
[   31.220837] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18F84002 | isr2
[   31.220839] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x04C37FDC | isr3
[   31.220841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   31.220844] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0023019C | last cmd Id
[   31.220846] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C5AB4 | wait_event
[   31.220848] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   31.220850] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   31.220853] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   31.220855] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   31.220857] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000004B | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   31.220860] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   31.220862] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00003088 | flow_handler
[   31.220922] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   31.220924] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000042, count: 7
[   31.220927] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000070 | NMI_INTERRUPT_LMAC_FATAL
[   31.220929] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   31.220932] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80456E90 | umac branchlink2
[   31.220934] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80455386 | umac interruptlink1
[   31.220936] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8045BA80 | umac interruptlink2
[   31.220938] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000400 | umac data1
[   31.220941] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8045BA80 | umac data2
[   31.220943] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[   31.220945] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003B | umac major
[   31.220948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x601F3A66 | umac minor
[   31.220950] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01A3A545 | frame pointer
[   31.220952] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887EE8 | stack pointer
[   31.220955] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00260119 | last host cmd
[   31.220957] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00100020 | isr status reg
[   31.220990] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   31.221009] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   31.221031] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   31.221052] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   31.221074] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A481 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   31.221096] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   31.221117] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   31.221138] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   31.221169] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   31.221199] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   31.221223] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   31.221244] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   31.221266] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   31.221443] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired.
[   31.221473] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW error in SYNC CMD REMOVE_STA
[   31.221548]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0x457/0x460 [iwlwifi]
[   31.221570]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x4e/0xc0 [iwlwifi]
[   31.221590]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd+0x1f/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[   31.221606]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd_pdu+0x51/0x70 [iwlmvm]
[   31.221623]  iwl_mvm_rm_sta_common+0x58/0xc0 [iwlmvm]
[   31.221640]  iwl_mvm_send_rm_bcast_sta+0x71/0x100 [iwlmvm]
[   31.221654]  iwl_mvm_rm_p2p_bcast_sta+0x19/0x50 [iwlmvm]
[   31.221667]  iwl_mvm_mac_remove_interface+0x20e/0x280 [iwlmvm]
[   31.221874] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to remove station. Id=1
[   31.221878] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed sending remove station
[   31.221883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to send binding (action:3): -5
[   31.221889] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PHY ctxt cmd error. ret=-5
[   31.221895] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to remove MAC context: -5
[   31.642352] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to remove MAC context: -5
[   31.642357] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LED command failed: -5
[   35.882016] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Exit CT Kill
[   36.906226] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x55f5, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[   36.906259] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0x80476eb8
[   36.906284] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x1492e
[   36.906309] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired.
[   36.906426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 59.601f3a66.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-59.ucode
[   36.906432] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   36.906436] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   36.906440] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   36.906444] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   36.906448] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   36.906452] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   36.906455] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data1
[   36.906459] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data2
[   36.906463] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[   36.906467] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   36.906471] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   36.906475] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   36.906479] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   36.906482] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   36.906486] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   36.906490] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   36.906494] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   36.906497] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   36.906501] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | board version
[   36.906505] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   36.906508] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   36.906512] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   36.906516] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   36.906519] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   36.906523] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   36.906526] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   36.906530] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   36.906534] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   36.906538] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   36.906542] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   36.906545] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   36.906549] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   36.906553] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   36.906557] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   36.906602] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   36.906607] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[   36.906611] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2000031C | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   36.906616] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   36.906620] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80456E90 | umac branchlink2
[   36.906623] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084F4C | umac interruptlink1
[   36.906649] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   36.906651] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | umac data1
[   36.906652] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0030AB38 | umac data2
[   36.906652] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[   36.906653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003B | umac major
[   36.906654] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x601F3A66 | umac minor
[   36.906655] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000D43E | frame pointer
[   36.906656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F14 | stack pointer
[   36.906657] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   36.906658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00100029 | isr status reg
[   36.906676] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   36.906679] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   36.906682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   36.906685] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   36.906688] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A481 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   36.906691] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   36.906694] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   36.906697] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   36.906700] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   36.906703] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   36.906708] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   36.906713] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   36.906718] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   36.906830] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired.
[   36.906854] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   36.906855] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[ 1163.622223] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5620, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[ 1163.622250] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0x80476eb8
[ 1163.622276] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x1492e
[ 1163.622281] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired.
[ 1163.622387] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 59.601f3a66.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-59.ucode
[ 1163.622391] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[ 1163.622394] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[ 1163.622396] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[ 1163.622399] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[ 1163.622401] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[ 1163.622403] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[ 1163.622405] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data1
[ 1163.622408] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data2
[ 1163.622410] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[ 1163.622412] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[ 1163.622414] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[ 1163.622417] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[ 1163.622419] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[ 1163.622421] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[ 1163.622423] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[ 1163.622426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[ 1163.622428] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[ 1163.622430] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hw version
[ 1163.622432] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | board version
[ 1163.622435] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[ 1163.622437] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr0
[ 1163.622439] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[ 1163.622441] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr2
[ 1163.622443] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr3
[ 1163.622446] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[ 1163.622448] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[ 1163.622450] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[ 1163.622452] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[ 1163.622455] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[ 1163.622457] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[ 1163.622459] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[ 1163.622461] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[ 1163.622464] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[ 1163.622466] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[ 1163.622511] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1163.622514] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000010, count: 7
[ 1163.622517] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2000031C | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[ 1163.622520] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[ 1163.622522] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80456E90 | umac branchlink2
[ 1163.622524] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084F4C | umac interruptlink1
[ 1163.622527] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[ 1163.622529] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | umac data1
[ 1163.622531] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0030AB38 | umac data2
[ 1163.622534] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[ 1163.622536] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003B | umac major
[ 1163.622538] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x601F3A66 | umac minor
[ 1163.622541] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000C4E6 | frame pointer
[ 1163.622543] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F14 | stack pointer
[ 1163.622546] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[ 1163.622548] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00100029 | isr status reg
[ 1163.622568] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[ 1163.622588] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[ 1163.622592] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[ 1163.622612] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 1163.622616] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A481 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[ 1163.622636] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[ 1163.622641] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[ 1163.622660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[ 1163.622665] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[ 1163.622684] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1163.622691] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1163.622712] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[ 1163.622734] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[ 1163.622754] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware error during reconfiguration - reprobe!
[ 1163.622759] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[ 1163.622762] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[ 1164.416565] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[ 1164.419071] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[ 1164.419090] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 65.3.35.22
[ 1164.419516] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[ 1164.419555] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x338
[ 1165.445931] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5595, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[ 1165.445957] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0x80476eb8
[ 1165.445983] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x1492e
[ 1165.445988] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired.
[ 1165.446090] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 59.601f3a66.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-59.ucode
[ 1165.446094] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[ 1165.446096] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[ 1165.446099] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[ 1165.446101] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[ 1165.446103] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[ 1165.446105] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[ 1165.446108] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data1
[ 1165.446110] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data2
[ 1165.446112] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[ 1165.446114] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[ 1165.446117] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[ 1165.446119] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[ 1165.446121] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[ 1165.446148] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[ 1165.446150] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[ 1165.446152] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[ 1165.446154] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[ 1165.446156] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hw version
[ 1165.446158] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | board version
[ 1165.446160] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[ 1165.446162] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr0
[ 1165.446163] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[ 1165.446165] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr2
[ 1165.446167] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr3
[ 1165.446169] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[ 1165.446171] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[ 1165.446173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[ 1165.446174] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[ 1165.446176] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[ 1165.446178] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[ 1165.446180] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[ 1165.446182] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[ 1165.446184] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[ 1165.446186] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[ 1165.446229] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1165.446232] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[ 1165.446234] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2000031C | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[ 1165.446237] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[ 1165.446239] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80456E90 | umac branchlink2
[ 1165.446241] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084F4C | umac interruptlink1
[ 1165.446243] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[ 1165.446244] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | umac data1
[ 1165.446247] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0030AB38 | umac data2
[ 1165.446248] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[ 1165.446250] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003B | umac major
[ 1165.446252] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x601F3A66 | umac minor
[ 1165.446254] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000C359 | frame pointer
[ 1165.446256] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F14 | stack pointer
[ 1165.446258] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[ 1165.446260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00100029 | isr status reg
[ 1165.446279] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[ 1165.446298] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[ 1165.446302] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[ 1165.446323] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 1165.446327] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A481 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[ 1165.446347] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[ 1165.446351] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[ 1165.446371] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[ 1165.446375] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[ 1165.446403] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1165.446421] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1165.446444] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[ 1165.446466] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[ 1165.446486] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[ 1165.845444] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Also adding wireless info script output [here](https://pastebin.com/ufamYV0j).

Answer (score 0):

I have issues with that wifi card on ubuntu 20.04, too. It disconnects randomly when it is connected to a quite slow wifi (about 7 Mbit/s), while with faster connections it works well. I am still figuring out what's going on. I'll let you know if I find a solution. In the meantime try to upgrade your kernel to the -57 version (`sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`)

Comment: You can atleast connect to wifi, but in my case, when I enable wifi, system freezes for a second and icon hides from the menu. In settings when I go to Wi-fi, it says "No Wifi Adapter Found".

Comment: Maybe it's not related at all, but what is your connection's speed? I suspect that slow connections are treated less efficiently (maybe a driver issue, since on windows the same wifi card works pretty well)

Comment: I am currently using 4G mobile network, which has atleast 300KBps internet speed. But it is connected via wired connection and not via WiFi.